Why is createElement() a part of the Legacy API?
In the pursuit to learn React in dept, I am trying to understand how does React creating a component element. "Under the hood" it is using the createElement() method, and all of the "children" like html elemnts and attributes, are treated as props.
I wanted to read more about it and for example How it differs from Javascript createElement(), but on their docs page I see that is a part of the Legacy API. React Legacy APIs

These APIs will be removed in a future major version of React.

Does that mean they don't use this method anymore, or won't use this method alongside other APIs in the list? Or does this mean it is not recommended to use createElement() method in our app as a method of choice?
I have read the React documentation and googled, but I haven't found an answer regarding the method in the context of my question.

createElement() is a browser API, it doesn't have anything to do directly with JavaScript other than the fact that you access browser APIs via JavaScript.

Yes good point. But they basically serve the same purpose in creating a Node, but as far as I understand it React creates a virtual DOM element (which are JS objects) and with JS it is a DOM element.

Just to be clear, createElement is not marked as deprecated in that docs page and as such is not being removed.

"Why is createElement() a part of the Legacy API?" "they are not recommended for use in newly written code" You should use JSX instead.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes I understood now, that it is not recomended. Thank you for the comments.

There is no createElement() method in plain Javascript. There are these two unrelated APIs:

The browsers DOM method document.createElement( tagName, options )
Reacts method React.createElement( type, props, ...children )

React.createElement is not planned to be removed. Your quote "These APIs will be removed in a future major version of React" belongs to the section "Deprecated APIs", but not to the section "Legacy APIs".
Details
In earlier versions, JSX code (old docs) was converted to React.createElement calls, and you could alternatively invoke React.createElement from Javascript, if you wouldn't use JSX.
Later the JSX transformation process was significantly changed, JSX would not be converted to React.createElement anymore, but to something more complicated. React recommends to use JSX (new docs) instead of React.createElement, but React always said explicitly that React.createElement "will continue to work and is not going away".
The current documentation of React.createElement says about JSX vs. React.createElement:

Both coding styles are fine, so you can use whichever one you prefer for your project

Under "Legacy APIs", the React documentation states "... they are not recommended ...", which is indeed confusing. I interpret this as "JSX is generally recommended, but React.createElement is also fine, if you want".
